# Log result table using Sipp

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sipp

So, sipp has -trace_msg and -trace_shortmsg
But is there a way to also log the table it outputs?

Basically I'd like a file that just quickly shows a count of messages succeeded and failed, essentially the table and it's counts for each message (because seeing where they failed would be good too). But I can't see an option for this.

I'm looking to run thousands of tests, with multiple different scenarios running in parallel, so I won't be able to check the tables once the test has finished or while the test is running.

Answer (score 0):

Found the command I was after.

-trace_screen

also -trace_stats seems quite useful